# Manually heat a "hot network question"

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

Give users<sup>1</sup> a UI to manually flag or vote a question on their site as being especially suitable as a "hot network question".

You could optionally limit how much this is used (e.g. no more than one topic per day or per week, per site), *and* keep whatever the current automated algorithm is ... just accept some explicit user input too.

Because, human users of the site might see that "this would be a good network question": a good advertisement for this site, and/or of interest to the wider community (of SE users outside this site).

Recognizing that a topic is especially suitable for other network users, is probably something that a site's trusted human users could do, but which SE's automated algorithm cannot.

I suspect this (human discernment) would make HNQs more interesting.

---

<sup>1</sup> That could mean "trusted users", "all users of the site", or whatever. To avoid confusing new users with extra UI, perhaps "all users above a reputation level".

My point is that the current algorithm selects questions interesting to users of the site.

In contrast, the human users might identify topics which are interesting to non-users of the site.

Answer (score 8):

No. The Hot Network Questions side bar is not a personal billboard.

The whole purpose of it is to show questions that the site community, as a whole, found interesting, not any single individual, be it trusted user, moderator, or even SE employee.

If such a user think a specific question deserves special advertisement, they can use the proper channels to promote it: their profile, social networks, etc.